# When can I adjust partition sized in Leopard?

Tags: mac-osx, partition

The version of Disk Utility that comes with Mac OS X 10.5 will let you [resize existing partitions](http://www.creativetechs.com/iq/leopard_disk_utility_can_resize_partitions.html) on a partitioned drive -- some of the time.  What determines if it will let you adjust partition sizes or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fragmentation would probably be the biggest problem. For a newly formatted partition, data will be added (more or less) from start to finish, however after a time fragmentation will leave blocks of data all over the disk. DiskUtil cannot resize a volume to a size less than the last block in use on the partition.

To defragment your partition, thereby moving all the data to the front of the disk, you can use a program like [iDefrag](http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iDefrag.php). Alternatively you can simulate the process by copying all your data off to another disk, reformating the volume, then copying it back. You can use a program like [SuperDuper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) or [Carbon Copy Cloner](http://www.bombich.com/software/ccc.html) to help with this process.

There may also be restrictions on resizing the startup volume. To avoid those, boot from the install DVD.

Comment: HFS+ can be defragged, in fact there's lots of options including iDefrag (http://www.coriolis-systems.com/iDefrag.php)

Comment: @Chopper3, I never knew about iDefrag. Thanks for the suggestion, i've updated my answer

Comment: I could adjust the sizes on the partitions on my startup drive, but not on an external drive (which had two HFS+ partitions).  This is what led me to believe some subtlety is involved.

Comment: What partition format are they, GPT, MBR or Apple Partition Map ?

Comment: I was just trying this again on another computer.  Trying to resize it failed.  I ran some tools (which weren't entirely clear), but it did seem to be fragmented.  I optimised it with Disk Warrior.  Then I tried to resize it again ... and it almost worked.  At the end, Disk Utility said it had lost its connection with an internal tool that it works with and needed to quit -- leaving me with an unmounted volume in who knows what sort of health.  Glad I backed up first!